# What is happening in this swift function?

Tags: ios, function, parameters, swift, xcode6

I'm trying to learn swift and wrap my brain around what's going on here. Any guidance at all would be greatly appreciated.

This example is from the [swift tour](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/GuidedTour.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH2-XID_1)

```
1. class Counter {
2.     var count: Int = 0
3.     func incrementBy(amount: Int, numberOfTimes times: Int) {
4.         count += amount * times
5.     }
6. }
7. var counter = Counter()
8. counter.incrementBy(2, numberOfTimes: 7)
```

question 1: On line three, why use 'numberOfTimes' instead of just 'times' on it's own?

question 2: On line eight, why do I need to pass the name of the parameter 'numberOfTimes' but not the name of the parameter 'amount'?

Comment: You'll find all your answers in [Function Parameter Names](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254)

Comment: Both: Because the author did not want to make the method clear to others. The #1 issue in good code is to make it easily readable and understandable by other developers.

Comment: @Antonio - if you post your comment as an answer I'd be glad to accept it. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Generally speaking, go to the iTunes book store and download the Swift book, it's free and should answer most of your questions about syntax.  Here, you're running into the Objective-C origins of Swift.  In both cases it's because it should be more explicitly clear what the function is doing.  It's incrementingBy 2 for 7 numberOfTimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find all your answers about *Function Parameter Names* in the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_254).

Specifically, you should read about *External Parameter Names*

Answer (score 2):

1°) A parameter can have an external name and an internal name. External name will be used when calling the method and internal name will be used inside the method. So you can use expressive method like `tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowInSection section:Int)` without having to use a long named parameter inside the function.

2°) Rules for methods : first parameters don't have to be named but the others needed to. This is for understanding matter. 
Example : `counter.incrementBy(2, 7)` ; here you can understand why `2` is used because of `incrementBy` but you can't understand what `7` is used for